# Is there any mechanism in kubernetes to automatically add annotation to new pods in a specific namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a namespace where new short-lived pods (< 1 minute) are created constantly by Apache Airflow. I want that all those new pods are annotated with `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true` automatically so that no CloudWatch metrics (container insights) are created for those pods.

I know that I can achieve that from airflow side with [pod mutation hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/kubernetes.html#pod-mutation-hook) but for the sake of the argument let's say that **I have no control over the configuration of that airflow instance**.

I have seen `MutatingAdmissionWebhook` and it seem that could do the trick, but it seems that it's considerable effort to set up. So I'm looking for a more of the shelf solution, I want to know if there is some "standard" admission controller  that can do this specific use case, without me having to deploy a web server and implement the api required by `MutatingAdmissionWebhook`.

**Is there any way to add that annotation from kubernetes side at pod creation time?** The annotation must be there "from the beginning", not added 5 seconds later,  otherwise the cwagent might pick it between the pod creation and the annotation being added.

Comment: Right now all I found is the same repo that @gohm'c found. Could you try this one and let as know if it works for you?

Comment: well, it's a fairly old repo / not maintained so in general I don't try that kind of thing. I'll went ahead and fixed it from the airflow side, adding those annotations there.

Comment: solution from airflow side https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438495/how-to-prevent-cloudwatch-container-insights-metrics-from-short-lived-kubernetes/71438496#71438496

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [repo](https://github.com/chickenzord/kube-annotate) which is a mutating admission webhook that does this. To date there's no built-in k8s support to do automatic annotation for specific namespace.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify I am posting community Wiki answer.

You had to use [`aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/blob/dd1be96164c2cd6226a33c8cf7ce10a7f29547cf/plugins/processors/k8sdecorator/stores/podstore.go#L31) annotation.  This means the pod that has one, it will be ignored by `amazon-cloudwatch-agent` / `cwagent`.

Here is the excerpt of your solution how to add this annotation to Apache Airflow:

> (...) In order to force Apache Airflow to add the
> `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true`  annotation to the task/worker pods and to the pods created by the `KubernetesPodOperator`  you will need to add the following to your helm  `values.yaml`  (assuming that you are using the "official" helm chart for airflow 2.2.3):

```yaml
airflowPodAnnotations:
  aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: "true"
airflowLocalSettings: |-
  def pod_mutation_hook(pod): 
    pod.metadata.annotations["aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore"] = "true"
```

> If you are not using the helm chart then you will need to change the `pod_template_file`  yourself to add the  `annotation`  and you will also need to modify the  `airflow_local_settings.py`  to include the `pod_mutation_hook`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71438495/how-to-prevent-cloudwatch-container-insights-metrics-from-short-lived-kubernetes/71438496#71438496) is the link to your whole answer.

Comment: This is not a solution to this specific question, that is a solution just for airflow running in kubernetes which I already linked in the comments see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420783/is-there-any-mechanism-in-kubernetes-to-automatically-add-annotation-to-new-pods/71639610#comment126269550_71420783 . This question is specifically about how to do the same from k8s side not from airflow side.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. About your issue - as I mentioned before I haven't found anything more than that [repo](https://github.com/chickenzord/kube-annotate) yet.