# How to prevent CloudWatch Container Insights metrics from short lived kubernetes pods started by Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow, amazon-cloudwatch

I have ~600000 metrics in my CloudWatch Metrics `CWAgent` namespace. 99% of them are undesired and are derived from very short lived pods.

I turns out that the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent` running on EKS will create a set of 5 metrics for each pod:

- `pod_memory_utilization`
- `pod_number_of_container_restarts`
- `pod_cpu_utilization`
- `pod_network_tx_bytes`
- `pod_network_rx_bytes`

Since I have Apache Airflow with the KubernetesExecutor running on that EKS cluster, a large number of really short lived pod are created regularly. Each task execution gets a pod that usually last a minute or so. So I end up with 5 new metrics for each execution, usually with a single datapoint or two (because I think it's one datapoint per minute).

These metrics are totally useless for me there are too many and there are not enough data points to actually do any interesting analysis/chart.

Is there anyway of preventing these metrics to be created in the first place?  I still want the metrics for my long running Pods and Deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent` has only one mechanism to control what gets ingested by the kubernetes plugin ([plugins/processors/k8sdecorator/stores/podstore.go](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/blob/dd1be96164c2cd6226a33c8cf7ce10a7f29547cf/plugins/processors/k8sdecorator/stores/podstore.go#L31)): the `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true` annotation in the Pod.

I don't think this annotation is officially documented but you can find it defined in the source code [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/blob/dd1be96164c2cd6226a33c8cf7ce10a7f29547cf/plugins/processors/k8sdecorator/stores/podstore.go#L31) and used [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/blob/dd1be96164c2cd6226a33c8cf7ce10a7f29547cf/plugins/processors/k8sdecorator/stores/podstore.go#L144-L146).

If a pod has the annotation `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true` it will be ignored by the amazon-cloudwatch-agent / cwagent and no container insights metrics will be generated for it.

You need to have amazon-cloudwatch-agent v1.247348.0 (2021-05-28) or later and your `cwagent-config.json` does NOT need to change, the "usual" `.logs.metrics_collected.kubernetes` is ok:

```
{
  "logs": {
    "metrics_collected": {
      "kubernetes": {
        "cluster_name": "${cluster_name}",
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60
      }
    },
    "force_flush_interval": 5
  },
  "metrics": {
    "metrics_collected": {
      "statsd": {
        "service_address": ":9125"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now in order to force Apache Airflow to add the `aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: true` annotation to the task/worker pods and to the pods created by the `KubernetesPodOperator` you will need to add the following to your helm `values.yaml` (assuming that you are using the "official" helm chart for airflow 2.2.3) :

```
airflowPodAnnotations:
  aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore: "true"
airflowLocalSettings: |-
  def pod_mutation_hook(pod): 
    pod.metadata.annotations["aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch-agent-ignore"] = "true"
```

If you are not using the helm chart then you will need to change the `pod_template_file` yourself to add the `annotation` and you will also need to modify the `airflow_local_settings.py` to include the `pod_mutation_hook`.